# Can Unity 2022 with ECS 1.0 be built onto the Quest 2 with scripting backend IL2CPP?

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, unity-dots, unity-ecs

I made a Unity 2022 project that uses ECS 1.0 which works fine in the editor and on the Rift S, but when I build it for the Quest 2 it crashes. If I switch to Mono it works. I had the same issue with 0.51.1.

This is my error log:

(*** Edit Unfortunately I didn't have debug loging setup properly and so not all of the symbols came through in my logcat, notice all of the (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc) and (Native Method) further down... ***)

```
    

2022/10/03 Error CRASH *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2022/10/03 Error CRASH Version '2022.2.0b9 (57355023f65f)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
2022/10/03 Error CRASH Build fingerprint: 'oculus/hollywood/hollywood:10/QQ3A.200805.001/44041400838600000:user/release-keys'
2022/10/03 Error CRASH Revision: '0'
2022/10/03 Error CRASH ABI: 'arm64'
2022/10/03 Error CRASH Timestamp: 2022-10-03 22:23:31.119674847-0700
2022/10/03 Error CRASH pid: 32326, tid: 32349, name: UnityMain  >>> com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test <<<
2022/10/03 Error CRASH uid: 10088
2022/10/03 Error CRASH signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr --------
2022/10/03 Error CRASH     x0  000000a250461a58  x1  0000007293b02d70  x2  0000007290896fc0  x3  000000000000000c
2022/10/03 Error CRASH     x4  00000072e8778c11  x5  0000007313e45118  x6  214e494253544f44  x7  214e494253544f44
2022/10/03 Error CRASH     x8  0000000000000001  x9  00000072901dc030  x10 00000072901dc038  x11 00000073594ad3c0
2022/10/03 Error CRASH     x12 411461b76d1cd77c  x13 00000000633bc352  x14 000c0a461bb43800  x15 0000ff486053b314
2022/10/03 Error CRASH     x16 0000007304cd6c70  x17 00000073ee73fec0  x18 00000072c01d3f48  x19 0000007313e538c0
2022/10/03 Error CRASH     x20 000000a2504619c0  x21 0000007304d2d420  x22 0000007304ed9000  x23 0000007294ca99d8
2022/10/03 Error CRASH     x24 0000000000000001  x25 00000073138f4840  x26 0000007301c82926  x27 0000000000000000
2022/10/03 Error CRASH     x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000007304d2db00
2022/10/03 Error CRASH     lr  00000073043b01f8  sp  0000007301142010  pc  000000730345e494  pst 0000000060001000
2022/10/03 Error CRASH 
2022/10/03 Error CRASH backtrace:
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #00 pc 0000000002316494  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #01 pc 00000000032681f4  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #02 pc 0000000003268184  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #03 pc 00000000035f7cd8  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #04 pc 0000000003605a64  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #05 pc 0000000003605754  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #06 pc 0000000003606900  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #07 pc 0000000003245444  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #08 pc 0000000003240848  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #09 pc 0000000003245444  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #10 pc 0000000003240848  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #11 pc 0000000003245444  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #12 pc 0000000001bbbde0  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #13 pc 0000000001bbbd04  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #14 pc 0000000000779724  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethodPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingArguments&, ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)+176) (BuildId: 3cb4cc3deefa59d5)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #15 pc 000000000078bb1c  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)+156) (BuildId: 3cb4cc3deefa59d5)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #16 pc 00000000005f9efc  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*)+272) (BuildId: 3cb4cc3deefa59d5)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #17 pc 00000000005f9e88  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*)+156) (BuildId: 3cb4cc3deefa59d5)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #18 pc 00000000005fa180  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (PlayerLoop()+324) (BuildId: 3cb4cc3deefa59d5)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #19 pc 000000000083a550  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (UnityPlayerLoop()+812) (BuildId: 3cb4cc3deefa59d5)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #20 pc 0000000000858c48  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+84) (BuildId: 3cb4cc3deefa59d5)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #21 pc 0000000000143950  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #22 pc 000000000013a934  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #23 pc 0000000000149640  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+244) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #24 pc 00000000002eb688  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+384) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #25 pc 00000000002e648c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+900) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #26 pc 00000000005b1ac4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+588) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #27 pc 0000000000134f14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #28 pc 00000000005b252c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1156) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #29 pc 0000000000134f94  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #30 pc 00000000005b1174  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1752) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #31 pc 0000000000135014  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #32 pc 00000000005af900  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1456) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #33 pc 0000000000134e14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #34 pc 00000000005b252c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1156) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #35 pc 0000000000134f94  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #36 pc 00000000002ba334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.15113868601603930265)+264) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #37 pc 00000000005a10b0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+964) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #38 pc 0000000000143a68  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #39 pc 000000000013a934  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #40 pc 0000000000149640  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+244) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #41 pc 00000000004be7c4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #42 pc 00000000004bf994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+416) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #43 pc 00000000004ffd14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1156) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #44 pc 00000000000d5c44  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36) (BuildId: 74793b832f73c27f2be0922f70cc8e16)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH       #45 pc 0000000000082fe4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 74793b832f73c27f2be0922f70cc8e16)
2022/10/03 Error CRASH Tombstone written to: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test/files/tombstone_01
0001/01/01 00:00:00.000 -1 -1 Info  --------- beginning of crash
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: UnityMain
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime Process: com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test, PID: 32326
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime Version '2022.2.0b9 (57355023f65f)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime Build fingerprint: 'oculus/hollywood/hollywood:10/QQ3A.200805.001/44041400838600000:user/release-keys'
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime Revision: '0'
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime ABI: 'arm64'
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime Timestamp: 2022-10-03 22:23:31.119674847-0700
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime pid: 32326, tid: 32349, name: UnityMain  >>> com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test <<<
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime uid: 10088
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr --------
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     x0  000000a250461a58  x1  0000007293b02d70  x2  0000007290896fc0  x3  000000000000000c
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     x4  00000072e8778c11  x5  0000007313e45118  x6  214e494253544f44  x7  214e494253544f44
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     x8  0000000000000001  x9  00000072901dc030  x10 00000072901dc038  x11 00000073594ad3c0
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     x12 411461b76d1cd77c  x13 00000000633bc352  x14 000c0a461bb43800  x15 0000ff486053b314
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     x16 0000007304cd6c70  x17 00000073ee73fec0  x18 00000072c01d3f48  x19 0000007313e538c0
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     x20 000000a2504619c0  x21 0000007304d2d420  x22 0000007304ed9000  x23 0000007294ca99d8
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     x24 0000000000000001  x25 00000073138f4840  x26 0000007301c82926  x27 0000000000000000
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000007304d2db00
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     lr  00000073043b01f8  sp  0000007301142010  pc  000000730345e494  pst 0000000060001000
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime 
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime backtrace:
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #00 pc 0000000002316494  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #01 pc 00000000032681f4  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #02 pc 0000000003268184  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #03 pc 00000000035f7cd8  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #04 pc 0000000003605a64  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #05 pc 0000000003605754  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #06 pc 0000000003606900  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #07 pc 0000000003245444  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #08 pc 0000000003240848  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #09 pc 0000000003245444  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #10 pc 0000000003240848  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #11 pc 0000000003245444  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #12 pc 0000000001bbbde0  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #13 pc 0000000001bbbd04  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95c44e0c0e9046bc)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #14 pc 0000000000779724  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethodPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingArguments&, ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)+176) (BuildId: 3cb4cc3deefa59d5)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #15 pc 000000000078bb1c  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)+156) (BuildId: 3cb4cc3deefa59d5)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #16 pc 00000000005f9efc  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*)+272) (BuildId: 3cb4cc3deefa59d5)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #17 pc 00000000005f9e88  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*)+156) (BuildId: 3cb4cc3deefa59d5)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #18 pc 00000000005fa180  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (PlayerLoop()+324) (BuildId: 3cb4cc3deefa59d5)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #19 pc 000000000083a550  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (UnityPlayerLoop()+812) (BuildId: 3cb4cc3deefa59d5)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #20 pc 0000000000858c48  /data/app/com.davidhopetech.DOTS1Test-xjIu-uc-4ZC6XGEXL8xFIQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+84) (BuildId: 3cb4cc3deefa59d5)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #21 pc 0000000000143950  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #22 pc 000000000013a934  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #23 pc 0000000000149640  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+244) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #24 pc 00000000002eb688  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+384) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #25 pc 00000000002e648c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+900) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #26 pc 00000000005b1ac4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+588) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #27 pc 0000000000134f14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #28 pc 00000000005b252c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1156) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #29 pc 0000000000134f94  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #30 pc 00000000005b1174  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1752) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #31 pc 0000000000135014  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #32 pc 00000000005af900  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1456) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #33 pc 0000000000134e14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #34 pc 00000000005b252c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1156) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #35 pc 0000000000134f94  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #36 pc 00000000002ba334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.15113868601603930265)+264) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #37 pc 00000000005a10b0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+964) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #38 pc 0000000000143a68  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #39 pc 000000000013a934  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #40 pc 0000000000149640  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+244) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #41 pc 00000000004be7c4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #42 pc 00000000004bf994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+416) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #43 pc 00000000004ffd14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1156) (BuildId: 21503a17cc72c012bec3947a961f2d93)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #44 pc 00000000000d5c44  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36) (BuildId: 74793b832f73c27f2be0922f70cc8e16)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime       #45 pc 0000000000082fe4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 74793b832f73c27f2be0922f70cc8e16)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime 
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libil2cpp.0x2316494(Native Method)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libil2cpp.0x32681f4(Native Method)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libil2cpp.0x3268184(Native Method)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libil2cpp.0x35f7cd8(Native Method)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libil2cpp.0x3605a64(Native Method)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libil2cpp.0x3605754(Native Method)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libil2cpp.0x3606900(Native Method)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libil2cpp.0x3245444(Native Method)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libil2cpp.0x3240848(Native Method)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libil2cpp.0x3245444(Native Method)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libil2cpp.0x3240848(Native Method)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libil2cpp.0x3245444(Native Method)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libil2cpp.0x1bbbde0(Native Method)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libil2cpp.0x1bbbd04(Native Method)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libunity.scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethodPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingArguments&, ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)(scripting_method_invoke:176)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libunity.ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)(Invoke:156)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libunity.ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*)(ExecutePlayerLoop:272)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libunity.ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*)(ExecutePlayerLoop:156)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libunity.PlayerLoop()(PlayerLoop:324)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libunity.UnityPlayerLoop()(UnityPlayerLoop:812)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libunity.nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)(nativeRender:84)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libart.art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline(art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline:144)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libart.art_quick_invoke_stub(art_quick_invoke_stub:548)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libart.art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)(Invoke:244)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libart.art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)(ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge:384)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libart.bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)(DoCall<false, false>:900)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libart.MterpInvokeDirect(MterpInvokeDirect:588)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libart.mterp_op_invoke_direct(mterp_op_invoke_direct:20)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libart.MterpInvokeStatic(MterpInvokeStatic:1156)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libart.mterp_op_invoke_static(mterp_op_invoke_static:20)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libart.MterpInvokeInterface(MterpInvokeInterface:1752)
2022/10/03 Error AndroidRuntime     at libart.mterp_op_invoke_interface(mterp_op_invoke_interface:20)
2022/10/03 Debug ActivityLifecycleListener onActivityPaused
2022/10/03 Info OpenXR nativeOnActivityPaused
2022/10/03 Info Unity onPause
2022/10/03 Info Process Sending signal. PID: 32326 SIG: 9
```

I've been looking for a solution for about 4 days with little success.

Is it possible to build a Unity 2022 project with ECS 1.0 on the Quest 2 with scripting backend IL2CPP?

Comment: Not a chance. Wait until it hits LTS.

Comment: Seems it might be related to a Unity 202x.x IL2CPP Bug. I will test again when this bug is fixed. Hopefully in the next release...

Comment: @AndrewŁukasik, so the question was CAN you make a build, not SHOULD you make a build...

Comment: Fair enough, good job with finding out the answer. It often comes down to determination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that there is a bug with IL2CPP builds that is causing the Quest 2 to crash with DOTS in Unity 2021.3.9+.

As far as I know right now you can not build a working build for the Quest 2 with IL2CPP and DOTS 1.0

Though this may be fixed on Unity 2022.0.0b11 and possibly regressed to older Unity versions.

So, hopefully in a few weeks this will be a non-issue...

HOWEVER,

You CAN build a working build for the Quest 2 with IL2CPP and DOTS 0.51.1 right now, but I only know of ONE version of Unity that will work for the build: UNITY 2021.3.8f1.